# DjangoRestFramework how to get user in viewset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

Im trying to make a friends feed that lists all "Beat" objects that i am currently friends with.  How can i access user inside of my viewset to return the correct objects?

MODELS:

```
class Beat(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField( default=datetime.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, blank=True)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to="media_files/audio/",null=True, blank=True)
    beat_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="media_files/img/",null=True, blank=True);
    admin_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

     def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.admin_name)



class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    admin_name = models.CharField(default="beat",max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="media_files/users/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.admin_name)
```

SERIALIZERS:

```
class AllBeatStreamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Beat
        fields = ('created_at', 'title', 'audio', 'artist' )
        depth = 1
```

VIEWSET:

```
class FriendsBeatStreamViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    user = self.request.user    
    my_battles = Battle.objects.filter(challenging_beat__artist=user)   
    obj = {}
    my_beats = Beat.objects.filter(artist=user)
    related_users = Relationship.objects.filter(from_user=user).values_list('to_user', flat=True).distinct()
    stream = Beat.objects.filter(artist__in=related_users)
    stream = list(my_beats) + list(stream) + list(my_battles)
    queryset = stream

    serializer_class = AllBeatStreamSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is simple: Override `get_queryset` instead of defining `queryset` as an attribute, and you'll be able to access the current user on `self.request.user`.

But your code sample is more complex. 1) You can't mix `Battle` object with `Beat` objects. 2) Your serializer is a `Beat` serializer, so your `queryset` must be of `Beat` instances.

But you can mix many sources of `Beat` using a filter with `or` causes in SQL, so you get all beats that are `my_beats OR related_to_me`. Django has a [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) that allow complex lookups. So you can join two `Q` objects using the `OR` operator `|`. Each `Q` with a filter that represents a `Beat` source, like `my beats` or `beats related to me`.

Your code will be something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class FriendsBeatStreamViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AllBeatStreamSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user

        my_beats = Q(artist=user)

        related_users = Relationship.objects \
            .filter(from_user=user).values_list('to_user', flat=True).distinct()
        stream = Q(artist__in=related_users)

        return Beat.objects.filter(my_beats | stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `queryset` attribute in serializer (where the logic belongs) like this:

```
class AllBeatStreamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs['context']['request'].user

        super(AllBeatStreamSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['parent'].queryset = self.get_request(user)

    def get_request(self, user):   
        my_battles = Battle.objects.filter(challenging_beat__artist=user)   
        obj = {}
        my_beats = Beat.objects.filter(artist=user)
        related_users = Relationship.objects.filter(from_user=user)\
                          .values_list('to_user', flat=True)\
                          .distinct()
        stream = Beat.objects.filter(artist__in=related_users)
        stream = list(my_beats) + list(stream) + list(my_battles)
        queryset = stream

        return queryset
```